# Can´t access array item with angular-template

Tags: angularjs, arrays, reference, angular-template

I have this code at below:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in Emotions" class="crop-item">
  <div class="text-left">
    <ul class="list-group no-buletts">

      <li class="list-group-item" style="width: 300px;">
        <img class="crop-img" alt="crop image" src="http://192.168.153.131:7000/tmp/{{Emotions['emotion-original-image-ref']}}.jpg.crop-{{$index}}.jpg"></img>
        Top score: {{Emotions["emotion-top-scores"].$index}}

      </li>

      <li ng-repeat='(scoreTitle,scoreValue) in person.scores' class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
            <label for="{{scoreTitle}}">{{scoreTitle}}: </label>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
            {{scoreValue * 100 | number:2}} %
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this "Emotions" object that have this content:

```
{
  "emotion-status-code": 200,
  "emotion-response": [{
    "faceRectangle": {
      "height": 72,
      "left": 147,
      "top": 122,
      "width": 72
    },
    "scores": {
      "anger": 0.00165787316,
      "contempt": 0.000218306363,
      "disgust": 0.0000283911031,
      "fear": 3.707502e-7,
      "happiness": 1.67207048e-8,
      "neutral": 0.948927,
      "sadness": 0.04916397,
      "surprise": 0.000004111683
    }
  }],
  "emotion-original-image-ref": "e8c3a383-bba8-4015-a9de-a5bbc70843b2",
  "emotion-top-scores": ["neutral"]
}
```

The problem is in the snippet right here:

```
Top score: {{Emotions["emotion-top-scores"].$index}}
```

I've checked the '$index' and it´s bringing the index as expected from 'ng-repeat' but I couldn't access the value and I don't know why. I believe I'm doing something silly. I tried to do this:

```
Top score: {{Emotions["emotion-top-scores"][$index]}}

Top score: {{Emotions["emotion-top-scores"][0]}}
```

And failing again.

Could you please help me in this "epic" situation, please?

Comment: what does {{Emotions["emotion-top-scores"]}} print

Comment: Prints nothing...

Comment: Ok, try accessing your property like that: Emotions.emotion-top-scores

Comment: Shows '0' . Seems the object is empty ?!?!

Comment: Print Emotions in console and if its not empty your json format could be wrong. It would be easier to help with a working plunker

Comment: Well, separating the 'emotion-top-scores' from the rest I have this

`Troubled array: ["neutral"]`

Comment: Can you add your controller

Comment: Yes, I can

controller: https://pastebin.com/EXbQG2Mu

service: https://pastebin.com/TwZmV9VF

Comment: Given the structure of `Emotions` you've shown here, I don't see how the initial `ng-repeat` is working. What is `person` at any given iteration? How would `person.scores` make any sense? This question would make a lot more sense if you gave an example of the output you get from this specific object.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I made it! But appealing to an ugly XHG. I´ve created a 'ng-model' variable and wrote the content of response body directly on this variable through controller. Works but sucks! In the controller...

```
$scope.topScores = res["emotion-top-scores"];
```

In the HTML

```
<li class="list-group-item" style="width: 300px;" ng-model="topScores" >
```

Hope there is better solution. That really sucks! I´m really shamed!